# MSAM32 вызов процедуры и присвоение WM_PAINT

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, окно

Взял код нескольких программ, но не понятны некоторые моменты.

```
.386

.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib


.DATA
ClassName db "SimpleWinClass",0
AppName  db "Our First Window",0
OurText  db "Win32 assembly is great and easy!",0
.DATA?
hInstance HINSTANCE ?
CommandLine LPSTR ?

.CODE
start:
    invoke GetModuleHandle, NULL
    mov    hInstance,eax
    invoke GetCommandLine
    mov CommandLine,eax
    invoke WinMain, hInstance,NULL,CommandLine, SW_SHOWDEFAULT
    invoke ExitProcess,eax
WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE, hPrevInst:HINSTANCE, CmdLine:LPSTR,
CmdShow:DWORD
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX
    LOCAL msg:MSG
    LOCAL hwnd:HWND

    mov   wc.cbSize,SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
    mov   wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW
    mov   wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc
    mov   wc.cbClsExtra,NULL
    mov   wc.cbWndExtra,NULL
    push  hInst
    pop   wc.hInstance
    mov   wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_WINDOW+1
    mov   wc.lpszMenuName,NULL
    mov   wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET ClassName
    invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov   wc.hIcon,eax
    mov   wc.hIconSm,eax
    invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW
    mov   wc.hCursor,eax
    invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc
    invoke CreateWindowEx,NULL,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,\
           CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL,NULL,\
           hInst,NULL
    mov   hwnd,eax
    invoke ShowWindow, hwnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL
    invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd
        .WHILE TRUE
               invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg,NULL,0,0
               .BREAK .IF (!eax)
               invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
               invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg
        .ENDW
        mov     eax,msg.wParam
        ret
WinMain endp

WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    LOCAL hdc:HDC
    LOCAL ps:PAINTSTRUCT
    LOCAL rect:RECT
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_PAINT
        invoke BeginPaint,hWnd, ADDR ps
        mov    hdc,eax
        invoke GetClientRect,hWnd, ADDR rect
        invoke DrawText, hdc,ADDR OurText,-1, ADDR rect, \
                DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER
        invoke EndPaint,hWnd, ADDR ps
    .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam
        ret
    .ENDIF
    xor   eax, eax

    ret
WndProc endp
end start
```

Первое: mov   wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc - это вызов процедуры? Как это работает?
Второе : как umsg получает значение WM_PAINT? C wmdestroy понятно - при закрытии.

Comment: 1) `mov wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc` в masm - то же самое, что `wc.lpfnWndProc =  (WNDPROC)WndProc;` в  си. 2)значение WM_PAINT, ровно как и другие, передаётся в параметр `umsg` при вызове оконной процедуры системой. 3) Прочитайте книгу Пирогова "Assembler для Windows" - там найдёте все ответы.